# gpg --import bind-9.9.4.tar.gz.sha1.asc fails with no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: gnu

This is the first time I figured I had better check the keys of the bind software I want to install.  So I downloaded what I think is a OpenPGP key ...

```
$ wget ftp://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.9.4/bind-9.9.4.tar.gz.sha1.asc
```

... then I tried to "import" this key like this ...

```
$ gpg --import bind-9.9.4.tar.gz.sha1.asc
```

... but I get this error message:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--import` is used to import keys, not to check a signature.

The `.asc` file is usually a detached GPG signature. If you have files `foo.tar.gz` and `foo.tar.gz.asc` (or `foo.tar.gz.sig`), then you can verify the file `foo.tar.gz` with:

```
gpg foo.tar.gz.asc
```

In your case however, the filename does not match that pattern so you should specify the `--verify` option explicitly. According to the manual page of gpg(1):

> --verify
>
> Assume that the first argument is a signed file  or  a  detached
>   signature  and  verify it without generating any output. With no
>   arguments, the signature packet is read from STDIN.  If  only  a
>   sigfile  is  given, it may be a complete signature or a detached
>   signature, in which case the signed stuff is expected in a  file 
>   without  the ".sig" or ".asc" extension.  With more than 1 argument,
>   the first should be a detached signature and the remaining files are
>   the signed stuff. To read the signed stuff from STDIN, use '-' as the
>   second filename.  For security reasons a detached signature  cannot 
>   read  the  signed material from STDIN without denoting it in the above
>   way.

Thus:

```
$ gpg --verify bind-9.9.4.tar.gz.sha1.asc bind-9.9.4.tar.gz
gpg: Signature made Wed 18 Sep 2013 09:25:43 PM CEST using RSA key ID 189CDBC5
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

Now, this key can be imported using:

```
gpg --recv-keys 189CDBC5
```

Be sure to verify this key. Ideally you would meet the person, but failing to do that, look at the trust others have in this key (Linux distributions, friends, etc). Remember that GPG is about a web of trust.

See also:

- [GPG Handbook - Making and verifying signatures](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN136)